# C++: Avoiding getters in showing some data

Tags: c++, oop, getter-setter

Let's say I have a class representing a person:

```
class Person {
  string name;
  int age;
}
```

I want to show the information about person on screen using class `Printer`

```
class Printer {
public:
  void print(string toPrint) { cout << toPrint << endl; }
}
```

Which of the following methods is a better practise:

1. To add getters to `Person` and then call them from outside (`main` method for instance):

   ```
   printerInstance.print(personInstance.getName + ", " + personInstance.getAge);
   ```
2. To add getters to `Person` but call them from the `Printer` (by overloading `print` method)

   ```
   printerInstance.print(personInstance);
   // ...
   Printer::print(Person person) {
     print(person.getName + ", " + person.getAge);
   }
   ```
3. To make `Person` depend on `Printer` (we are avoiding `getter`) and call:

   ```
   personInstance.print(printerInstance);
   // ...
   Person::print(Printer printer)
   {
     printer.print(getName + ", " + getAge);
   }
   ```

Comment: One level of abstraction above your actual question: Wouldn't an overloaded `<<` operator be the more "idiomatic" way to solve this?

Comment: @Marco13 If the limit showing data to `cout` - yes. But in my question it is just an example and I'd like to find the answer that applies not only to printing in console but also to showing data in GUI.

Comment: Then another, (4th) option (from a Java guy ;-)) : You might consider offering a `toString` method (or, if you prefer: `to_string`) that only returns a "sensible" string representation of the object, without explicitly exposing internal details of the class.

Answer (score 2):

I usually follow Scott Meyer's advices to "prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions".

He says that the higher level of encapsulation is when the lowest number of function have access to the private members of the class, which sounds like a reasonable definition.

So in my opinion, solution 2 is the best one you propose (but I'd favour an `operator<<`).

One important note however: this does not stand anymore if the data you have to expose (through getters) for your printer is something that you would not expose otherwise. The idea of encapsulation is to protect your internals so that you can change your implementation in the future. If you expose your internals just for the printer, you risk clients using your getters and won't be able to remove them later. In this case, a `toString` or `toStream` method seems better.

If you are certain that in the future you'll always have a `getAge` and a `getName` methods even if you stop using a `int age` and `std::string name` internally (for example computing age from birthdate) then it's fine.

Comment: Two last paragraphs are essential for my question - I want to avoid exposing `Person`'s internals. Therefore, I'm not convinced to 1. and 2. methods from the question. In other hand, the disadvantage of 3. one is that `Person` depends on `Printer`.

Comment: Then I would advise the `toStream` method that can be called by a non-friend non-member `operator<<` for ease of use.